# How do I manually insert a database into a Android project?

Tags: android

The database file is identified by [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) when I insert it via the Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS), but when I add the database to the project assest it doesn't even upload to the device (as I can see through the DDMS). How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `sqlite` db to the `assets` folder will not make it available for you to use it.
Your db should be copied to `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/` on the first run.

Check [this link](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

Comment: i have done this allready ,  i deduced that my problem were'nt there my first  query wa lacking a space (" ") so i just burned a day to figure it out :(