# Use custom SQLite database for Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Say I want to create a database using the Android SDK's sqlite tool. What would the file extension have to be? I would think .db or .sqlite3 or .sqlite? How would I import it in my source code (Is there a method I should call?) and where in my source code? I was thinking in the onCreate method of a class that implements [`SqliteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123610/how-do-i-insert-manualy-db-into-android-project

Comment: @ognian - No it's not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My open source app does exactly this, so feel free to copy-and-paste the parts you need:
https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/blob/master/src/com/ichi2/anki/AnkiDb.java

You can name the files the extension you want. I call my files "somefilename.anki" because Anki is the name of the associated desktop software, but feel free to use any filename extension.